# url in resetpassword email not returning view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

im reseting my password in mvc using email,the code looks fine i can send token to email.but when i click on link in email it doesn,t redirect me to the reset password page

here is my code in emailreset action

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        //SendSmsBusiness objap = new SendSmsBusiness();
        RegisterBusiness reg = new RegisterBusiness();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();
            user = reg.UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);

            // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
            // Send an email with this link
            if (user != null)
            {
                string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol:Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
            }

            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user does not exist");
                return View();
            }
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

i don,t know if my request.url.scheme is null because i do have a resetpassword page. here is its view.

```
 @model Template.Model.ResetPasswordViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Reset password";
 }

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ResetPassword", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<hr />
@Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading " style="background-color: green;"></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Code, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Code, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />

    </div>
</div>
}
@section Scripts {
@System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

any help appreciated.

the resetpassword controller

```
   // GET: /Account/ResetPassword
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ResetPassword(string code)
    {
        return code == null ? View("Error") : View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/ResetPassword
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        RegisterBusiness reg = new RegisterBusiness();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();
            user = reg.UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "No user found.");
                return View();
            }
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, model.Code, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
                return View();
            }
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Could you post ResetPassword action in Account controller? That is the action that will be called when the url is clicked. Also have you double checked that the url you sent is in an acceptable format for said action?

Comment: @Daniel here is the resetpassword action controller

Comment: If you breakpoint that method, does it get hit? Can you step through the code? Are any errors thrown?

Comment: i managed to get it working @Daniel thanks for the idea of stepping through the code.